# Tableau summing measures

Tags: tableau-api

I have a record of customer id and number of purchases by year.  I'd like to find a sum of how many customers purchased by year.  For example, between 2010-2018, I need counts of customers purchasing  once, twice, three times, etc up to eight times
thanks in advance

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: Take a look at LOD calcs. https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/02/lod-uses.html